# Upload all files from directory

Tags: jsf, file-upload, directory

I have been trying to upload all files from a directory to the server side by selecting the directory itself . Here what i have come up with

```
<input id="myfiles" type="file" value="Browser Folder"  webkitdirectory="" directory=""/>
<h:commandButton value ="upload" onclick="uploadFolder()"/>
```

and I do something like this on the Javascript function

```
function uploadFolder() {

var files = document.getElementById('myfiles').files;

for (var i=0, file; file=files[i]; i++) {

           //do something here.
}
```

It is possible to pass those file to the bean in order to upload them one by one? 
My current upload function gets the file from a private Part variable.

Comment: Are you using HTML 5? Files cannot be uploaded via AJAX/JavaScript. You have to use either HTML 5 or hidden iframes which may be provided/supported by some readily available jQuery plug-ins.

Comment: So in other words it cant be done with JSF and javascript alone?

Comment: Only if you use HTML 5 to read files through the JavaScript language or hidden iframes as stated earlier. I am unfamiliar with the third technique, if any. JSF component libraries like PrimeFaces provide component(s) out of the box to upload files via AJAX. Besides PrimeFaces, I am not familiar with other libraries.